# Rename managed Package Class Name

Tags: apex, managed-package, upgrade

I created a released managed package lately and I installed it on my other salesforce org. Now, I want to update some class names of my managed package. Is this possible? Or will it not give some problem when I upgrade the package and also upgrade it in my other salesforce org?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Salesforce won't let you change the name. If it does, though, be aware that the old name will probably end up being "reserved" and won't be able to be used in a future release. All that said, though, you may as well try it out and see what happens. There's no way you can change your package in a way that will prevent the package from being installed.

Comment: @sfdcfox I've tried renaming the name and you are right. Salesforce won't let me change the name. Thanks mate.

Comment: We had various questions like this. To test out, we create a small devorg and use it produce managed package and install it in other orgs and try out. Another gotcha we had was that, if you release global interface, you cannot add new methods to that. It makes sense if you think about it, but hard to visualize when you are heads down building the package.