# Can i changed apex class Name After Managed package Realsed

Tags: appexchange

I want to Change apex class Name After Managed package is Realsed.

Comment: Have a look on [Rename managed Package Class Name](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/211258/rename-managed-package-class-name)

Comment: can you Please suggest me what are the things that can be Restrict on apex class after Released managed package

Comment: @BabluKumar I'd suggest opening a new post for that question since it's a separate question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Components Available in Managed Packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_packageable_components.htm) and [Special Behavior of Components in Packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_component_behavior.htm) covers most everything you need to know about all the special behaviors and restrictions you should know about.

Generally speaking, however, you're restricted from doing anything that could break a subscriber's org. You can apply this logic just by thinking about it. For example, if you could rename a class, what would happen to a subscriber's org if they were using that class? (hint: it'd cause compilation errors, permanently locking them out of the ability to upgrade).

There are cases where you can have support open up the ability to delete extra components that aren't normally deletable, but if you enable this feature and delete a class, you can never, ever reuse that class name in your package, ever. Generally speaking, unless it's a name you would never think to use in the future, you might just want to leave it be.